# Pandas - Data Frame - Reshaping Values in Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas and have a data frame with a team's score in 2 separate columns. This is what I have.

```
Game_ID Teams   Score

1    Team A  95
1    Team B  85
2    Team C  90
2    Team D  72
```

This is where I would like to get to and then ideally to.

```
1   Team A  95 Team B  94
2   Team C  90 Team B  72
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking to do here. From your first dataframe to the next, there does not seem to be any consistencies in terms of numbers or teams: `94` is in the second dataframe but not in the first one; and `Team B` is in the second dataframe twice, but only once in the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that games always involve exactly 2 teams, we can manipulate the underlying numpy array.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values[:, 1:].reshape(-1, 4),
             pd.Index(df.values[::2, 0], name='Game_ID'),
             ['Team', 'Score'] * 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try something as follows: Create a `row_id` within each group by the `Game_ID` and then unstack by the `row_id` which will transform your data to wide format:

```
import pandas as pd
df['row_id'] = df.groupby('Game_ID').Game_ID.transform(lambda g: pd.Series(range(g.size)))
df.set_index(['row_id', 'Game_ID']).unstack(level=0).sortlevel(level = 1, axis = 1)
```

[image]

*Update*:

If the `row_id` is preferred to be dropped, you can drop the level from the columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['row_id', 'Game_ID']).unstack(level=0).sortlevel(level = 1, axis = 1)   
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(level = 1)
df1
```

[image]

Comment: Finally drop row_id level, FTW